# Run "FindNext" only if button is clicked in userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm setting up a userform to find a company's name. Each company has 10 rows of data. I need the button to select the first row and then stop and only run the findnext if button is clicked again.

Currently my code finds the company's name correctly, but because of the loop it directly select the last row with the company's name. I need it to select the first time the name appears and then findnext only if I click on the button again

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, c As String
Dim mycell As Range

lastrow = Sheets("Rent Roll").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
c = TextBox1.Text

With Sheets("Rent Roll").Range("C5:C" & lastrow)
Set mycell = .Find(what:=c, LookIn:=xlValues)

If Not mycell Is Nothing Then
firstAddress = mycell.Address

   Do
   mycell.Select

   Set mycell = .FindNext(mycell)

   Loop While Not mycell Is Nothing And mycell.Address <> firstAddress

Else
MsgBox ("Not Found")

End If

End With

Exit Sub


End Sub
```

If I enter "Google", it should select the first row and then stop. Then if I click the button again, use findnext and select the next cell with "Google"

Comment: `Loop While Not mycell Is Nothing And mycell.Address <> firstAddress` - the `And` operator does not short-circuit in VBA, so `myCell.Address` will still be evaluated even when `mycell Is Nothing`: that will throw error 91.

Comment: Add a global variable to track the "found" cell (and one to track the search term) - each time you click the button you can perform the search again, using the "After" argument to start where you last left off.

Comment: Are you showing the userform non-modally?

Comment: Thank you @TimWilliams I added two separate buttons, one that finds the first entry and another button that find the next entry after the active cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to to something like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Static lastCell As Range  '<< static variables preserve values between calls
    Static lastTerm As String

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngSrch As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long, c As String
    Dim f As Range, afterCell As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Rent Roll")
    Set rngSrch = ws.Range(ws.Range("C5"), ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))

    c = TextBox1.Text

    'new search term?
    If c <> lastTerm Then
        Set lastCell = Nothing
        lastTerm = c
    End If

    If Len(c) = 0 Then Exit Sub '<< nothing to search for

    If lastCell Is Nothing Then
        Set afterCell = Rng.Cells(Rng.Cells.Count)
    Else
        Set afterCell = lastCell
    End If

    Set f = rngSrch.Find(what:=c, after:=afterCell, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If f Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("'" & c & "' not found")
    Else
        If f.Row < lastCell.Row Then
            MsgBox "Already at the last row" '<< do this, or just keep wrapping round?
        Else
            f.Select
            Set lastCell = f
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```